# Robovm: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/robovm/objc/$M

Tags: java, robovm

I have a problem every time I run my app that was built using libgdx/robovm. The build succeeds, but every time I open the app, I get the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/robovm/objc/$M
    at org.robovm.apple.foundation.NSObject.init(NSObject.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.foundation.NSObject.<init>(NSObject.java)
    at org.robovm.apple.foundation.NSAutoreleasePool.<init>(NSAutoreleasePool.java)
    at my.app.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java)
```

I'm using the latest versions of robovm, Xcode, and JDK 8.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: It seems some dependency is missing and it is not able to locate a class `NSObject`due to that.

Comment: looks like your classpath is incomplete and you need more jar files in your path.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what caused this exception, but updating to LibGDX 1.6.0 and RoboVM 1.2.0 solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after updating RoboVM in Eclipse to version 1.2.0.

Setting `roboVMVersion` to `1.2.0` in the libgdx project's main `build.gradle` file fixed it. Make sure to do `Gradle` > `Refresh All` on your projects in Eclipse afterwards.